# Showing Existence of Antiderivative for Complex-Valued Function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I am asked to show that for $z\in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0,1\}$, there exists an analytic (single-valued) function, $F(z)$ on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0,1\}$, such that $F'=f$, where $$f(z) = \frac{(1-2z)\cos(2\pi z)}{z^2 (1-z)^2}$$
I know that if $$\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz =0$$ for all closed contours, $\gamma$, then $f$ has an antiderivative. Furthermore, in the case of the given function above, $f(z)$, I know that Res$(f,0)=$ Res$(f,1)=0$, so using the Residue Theorem I know that for any simple closed contour, $\gamma$, we have $$\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz =0$$

However, to ensure that $f$ has an antiderivative, I need to show that this is true for all closed $\gamma$, not just simple closed $\gamma$. How can I go about finishing this last step of the proof?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Taylor series expansion of cosine? If so, the result follows immediately by considering the uniform convergence of the series on proper domains.

Comment: The [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) holds for all (rectifiable) closed curves. Which version are you referring to?

Comment: For general rectifiable closed curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,1\}$, we have $$\int_{\gamma}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=2\pi i \sum_{z_0\in\{0,1\}}\operatorname{wind}(f,z_0)\operatorname{Res}(f,z_0),$$ where $$\operatorname{wind}(f,z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}\in\mathbb{Z}$$ is the winding number. It can be proved by deforming $\gamma$ into a formal linear combination of simple closed curves.

Comment: What I was trying to emphasize is that in showing that the antiderivative of a certain function exists, one may try to construct a series expansion of the function and try to show that it converges uniformly on some domain. So that you can integrate (here I mean the inverse process of differentiation) the series term by term to find the antiderivative explicitly.

Comment: In this case, Taylor series expansion of cosine might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution. Write

$$ g(z) = f(z) - \left( \frac{1}{z^2} - \frac{1}{(z-1)^2} \right). $$

Then $g$ has removable singularities at both $z=0$ and $z=1$, and so, $g$ extends to a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$. In particular, $g$ has an antiderivative, say $G(z)$. Then

$$ f(z) = g(z) + \frac{1}{z^2} - \frac{1}{(z-1)^2} $$

has an antideriviative

$$ G(z) - \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z-1}. $$

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm trying to follow your reasoning where you conclude that $g$ has an antiderivative. You say $g$ extends to a holomorphic function and so, in particular, $g$ has an antiderivative. However, just because a function is holomorphic does not mean that it has an antiderivative. As Martin pointed to in a comment above, $1/z$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ yet does not have a holomorphic antiderivative.

Comment: @FrenchToastCrunch, The crucial difference here is that the domain of $g$ is all of $\mathbb{C}$, which is simply connected. In such case, a holomorphic function always admits an antiderivative. (That is why we bother to remove the poles in this solution!) Alternatively, since $g$ is analytic on all of $\mathbb{C}$, it admits Taylor series that converges to $g$ on all of $\mathbb{C}$, and so, its antiderivative can be represented explicitly via termwise integration.

Comment: I see, I'm following now. The last bit I need to put the pieces together is understanding why, if $g$ is a function with removable discontinuities, it extends to a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$. My basic knowledge of analytic continuation is that if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are analytic on domains $D_1$ and $D_2$, respectively, and $f_1=f_2$ on $D_1 \cap D_2$, where $D_1 \cap D_2$ is non-empty, then $f_2$ is the analytic continuation of $f_1$ on $D_2$. I'm trying to use this to conclude what you did about the extension of $g$.If you can clear up this last step I'd be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: @FrenchToastCrunch, It seems that you have not learned [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem) yet. The proof is actually short, and is included in the link.

Answer (score 2):

The [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) states that for any (rectifiable) closed curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0,1\}$:
$$
\int _{\gamma }f(z)\,dz=2\pi i \bigl( \operatorname {I} (\gamma ,0)\operatorname {Res} (f,0) + \operatorname {I} (\gamma ,1)\operatorname {Res} (f,1) \bigr) 
$$
and that is zero for the given function $f$ because both residues are zero (as you already calculated).

Alternatively you could use that
$$
 f(z) = \frac{\cos(2 \pi z)}{z^2} - \frac{\cos(2 \pi (z-1))}{(z-1)^2}
$$
and show that $\frac{\cos(2 \pi z)}{z^2}$ has an antiderivative in $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: What is $I(\gamma,0)$?  Is that an indicator function specifying that the curve $\gamma$ encloses the point $0$?

Comment: @mjw: It is the [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) of $\gamma$ with respect to the point $0$.

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Comment: @MartinR : Thank you for your response, in the link you provided, the claim is that the Residue Theorem holds for any rectifiable closed curve in $U$, where $U$ is a simply connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. However, $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0,1\}$ is not a simply connected set. I like your alternate suggestion but ultimately I'd be faced with the same problem I was running into. Following along with your suggestion, how do you show $\cos(2 \pi z)/z^2$ has an antiderivative in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: @FrenchToastCrunch: No, the residue theorem requires  that $\gamma$ is a closed curve in $U \setminus \{a_1, \ldots, a_n \}$ and $U$ is simply connected. Here $U = \Bbb C$ and $ \{a_1, \ldots, a_n \} = \{ 0, 1 \}$. – For $\cos(2 \pi z)/z^2$ in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ you could consider the Taylor series and integrate it term-by-term.

Comment: Ah yes, you're correct. However, it seems like we still need to assume that $\gamma$ is rectifiable, no? Is it true that if the contour integral of $f$ is zero over all rectifiable closed curves, then its contour integral over all general closed curves is zero?

Comment: @FrenchToastCrunch: The curve integral is only defined for rectifiable curves.

Comment: @FrenchToastCrunch: Note that it would be sufficient to show that $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=0$ for all piecewise differentiable curves in the domain, or for all curves consisting of segments parallel to the x or y axis. That allows you to define an antiderivate  $F(z) = \int_{z_0}^z f(z) dz$, where the integral is taken along any (piecewise differentiable, or axis-parallel) curve from $z_0$ to $z$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{0,1\}$ because $f$ is the quotient of holomorphic functions.  Since $f$ is holomorphic in this set, it has a primitive $F$ there so that $F^\prime=f$.  Or is the question to find $F$?

**UPDATE**

This answer is not complete.  Leaving it here for a while because the comment from @Martin R was helpful.

Comment: A holomorphic function does not necessarily have a (holomorphic) antiderivative. The standard counterexample is $1/z$ in $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}$. – Your argument would only work in a *simply-connected* domain.

Comment: Okay, so (in general) there is not necessarily an $F$ that works for the whole set, if not for every closed curve $\gamma$, $\oint_\gamma f(z) \,dz = 0$.  I am glad I attempted an answer.  I learned something.  Thank you!